# FILE extension changing while copying from Ubuntu to windows

Tags: windows, files, file-format, file-type

I downloaded data in Ubuntu which has an extension .text/plain bit when I copied it to my Windows 10 through USB the file extension is changed to '.file'. What should I do now to open it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Ubuntu doesn't use extensions so it wouldn't be Ubuntu that is changing the name of the file.  Whatever program you are using to copy/transfer the file to windows (most likely on the windows end) is changing the filename as a means of 'security' (as windows uses extension to control action; Ubuntu uses file contents).  If you `file filename` (where filename is the name of your file) you can view the type of file according to Ubuntu or any \*nix)

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu certainly does use file extensions to the same extent Windows does. File extensions are standardised by IANA along with media types and shells such as Gnome and KDE use them for identifying icons and appropriate actions, which is exactly what Windows Explorer does.

Comment: @Ben NO. Linux does not. Extensions are there to make it easier for humans to see what the file is. There is software for the desktop (!= Linux) that expect files to be named with an extension but Linux in itself does not care about that.  And even then: the extensions are matched with a mime-type list.

Comment: @Rinzwind Ubuntu = linux distribution(s), and **Ubuntu** certainly **does** use extensions. Linux kernel also uses extensions for some limited purposes, e.g. loader locating so files. Overall Linux distributions use extensions for the same purposes as Windows, and used by the equivalent components, Windows Explorer being the equivalent of the Linux graphical shells like Gnome and KDE. It's possible to install Windows without the graphical shell, in which case most uses of file extensions will not occur.

Comment: The desktop does but only to make things speed up a little bit. If those desktop coders would follow the correct method they too would scan for the 1st few bytes like linux does. And no: linux and ubuntu is not the same. Ubuntu is the desktop built on top of Linux.Those few tweaks made to the kernel don't matter

Comment: @Rinzwind Why do you think that magic numbers is "the correct method"? It works for some file types but not others. There are important reasons why the file extension is a better choice than attempting to sniff the file bytes, it requires more disk accesses = more time, and consumes more power in mobile devices, and is not reliable anyway. File extensions is in practice the best answer to the problem of identifying file types, which is why everyone uses them now including Ubuntu and Windows. Even file formats which use magic numbers also use file extensions, because it is a better solution.

Comment: @ben if windows would use it 50% of malware and virusses would die. Yes, file extensions are sometimes easier to but it is making a system LESS secure if you depend on it without actually checking if a file is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that the file extension is `.text/plain`???? I'm 99% sure that it's not possible. Maybe you are talking about file content?
Can you show us the output of runing `file your_filewith_strange_extension`?
To open it on Windows, it should be enough renaming its extension to something you know. Do you know what type of file it is? if you downloaded a plain text file, you can rename it to `your_filewith_strange_extension.txt`. The output of running (on linux) `file your_filewith_strange_extension` should give you a hint about the file contents if you don't know what it is

Comment: The Readme.txt within the data says that it is .json file extention. im not able to open it, and when i opened it through .txt extension i cant able to load the data since it so 450Mb size.

Comment: @ammu if it's a json file, the content type is something like `application/json`, `text/plain` or something similar, but that's not the extension of the file.
The extension could be `.json`, `.txt`, nothing at all, anything, etc. In unix, the extension is not important (well, originally, now sometimes it does).
If you need to open it in Windows and you have to guess, I'll go with `.json`or `.txt` as my firsts guesses

Comment: @ammu if in linux you run `head the_450mb_file.json`, what shows you? it seems like the starting of a json file? and if you run `tail the_450mb_file.json`??? 
The idea is that you can see if it's a real json or not.
The only way I could open big files on windows was with notepad++, but the last time I did it was like 10 years ago

Comment: actually the content is latex file of a paper, but the extension is given as file. i cant able to load the data as .txt

Comment: So, to summarize: the file extension couldn't be `text/plain`, because file names can't have `/` on it. Also, latex content-type is `application/x-latex`, not `text/plain`.
Maybe you have a latex file that when you open it, it shows json data? something similar to having a .docx file that when you open it with microsoft word, inside you see a json? (`{key1: val1, key2: val2, (...)}`). If that's the case, you can open it with a latex editor, (https://latexbase.com is an online editor), if it's ok, you can rename your file to something.tex

Answer (score 9):

It [appears](https://fileinfo.com/extension/file) that Windows adds the `.file` extension to any file with an extension it doesn't know/recognise. Understandable, because `text/plain` is not a file extension but [rather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension#Alternatives) a 'content type'.

It seems that opening the file has worked on Ubuntu, because GNOME can "associate a media type with a file by examining both the filename suffix and the contents of the file" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension#Alternatives)).

To open the file in Windows, you can simply change the extension from `.file` to `.txt`, which is the most likely filetype. However, depending on where and for what purpose you downloaded the file, it [could](https://www.solvusoft.com/en/mime-multipurpose-internet-mail-extensions/text/text-plain/) also be a `.dat` (data) or other file. If you don't know how to change the file type, I'd advice to Google for it as that seems out of scope for this Ubuntu-oriented site :)

Comment: Nice one. Just a pointer you can always expand/modify your answer (by clicking 'edit' below it) instead of deleting it and posting a new one :) Similarly you can '*undelete*' an answer you deleted.

Comment: More to the point, in Windows the character `/` in `filename.text/plain` is not a valid character for a filename. In Windows, filenames are not arbitrary sequences of bytes but a user-interface element with restrictions placed upon them to serve that purpose. Therefore control characters, and special shell metacharacters are not allowed. Whatever utility the poster used to copy the file has taken care of this issue.

Comment: @Ben This restriction (no `/` in filenames) also holds for Linux. AFAIR, there are only two forbidden characters in a Linux filename: `/` and `\0`. This means the file the OP downloaded CANNOT have an extension of `.plain/text`.